# Django: dynamic url via submit button

Tags: django, url, button, dynamic

I want to use a dynamical url with Django for a search option in my database. I implemented an input text field for my search term and a submit button to start the query. So, when I click the button the new url of my search result should include the term from the text field (written by the user).

How can I implement a **dynamic url using a submit button** instead of a hyperlink? How do I get the value of my text field into my url? Can you please help me?

That is part of my (non-working) code:

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
url(r'^$', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),   
url(r'^search/(?P<term>\w{2}_[0-9.]+)/$', views.search, name='search'),)
```

views.py

```
def search(request, term ):
    search_term = request.GET['term']
    #generate results for search_term
    return render(request, 'app/results.html', {'list_of_r': list_of_r})
```

results.html

```
<form action="{% url 'app:search/{{term}}' %}" method="get">
{% csrf_token %}
             <input id="text_id" type="text"  name="term" maxlength="20"  />
             <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Why not use JS for such a task? fetch the term from the input, put some validation and assign it to the url.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, I am not very familiar with js. I found django-js-reverse, which might work somehow. However, i do not know how to connect django template to js. Can you give me some more hints for your suggested solution? :)  How would you fetch the input? How can I assign the url back to my form action?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not how you do forms: but you don't need to. The GET request submitted by the form automatically includes the parameters in the form, that's the whole point: so if you submitted to the path `/search`, with the value "text_to_be_searched" in your term field, the URL woudl be "/search?term=text_to_be_searched". You don't need to do anything else.

Comment: but now I have all the paramaters  
/search/?csrfmiddlewaretoken=YYABC&term=text_to_be_searched
&submit=SUBMIT
can I select just one of the paramters to be displayed like this?
/search/term=text_to_be_searched

Comment: You don't need a CSRF token in a GET form.

Comment: thanks :) is there also a possibility to prevent the "submit" parameter or any other form parameter to appear in my url? (except my search term)